# Bootstrap thumbnails maintaining height with angular-vertilize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an **ng-repeat** that loops on items to display them in **bootstrap thumbnails**.

Since data is dynamic, I used **angular-vertilize** module to give the same height to the thumbnails.

```
<div vertilize-container class="row">
<div ng-repeat="story in news" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div vertilize class="thumbnail">
      <img src="{{story.imgpath}}" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>{{story.title}}</h3>
        <p>{{story.subtitle}}</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**angular-vertilize** succeeded in giving the same size for the thumbnails:

- When navigating between different states (views) within the site.

[image: Correct display]

But when

- **RELOADING** the site by clicking on the reload button

OR

- Entering manually the url of the page and hitting Enter

[image: Wrong display]

The content doesn't display correctly. However, resizing the browser size simply adjusts the content to be displayed correctly.

I think that while bootstrap trying to resize the images, vertilize is calculating the height of the thumbnails, and that's why the display crashes. Without having images, it works.

Running plnkr example: http://plnkr.co/edit/hT420wt10F5p02gOQu2M?p=preview

A link to angular vertilize module: http://sixthdim.github.io/angular-vertilize/ (after I searched for a while, I found it as the best one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes up because your image resource is loaded async. In the moment `angular-vertilize` is executed the image resource is not loaded so the auto resize failed. I extended the missing feature for "async" resource loading in `angular-vertilize` v1.0.1. I fixed the problem in a clean way without having fixed image heights work with. In this way you are able to have responsive images.

Just add the new child directive `vertilize-resource` to all async loaded resources inside your `vertilize-container` to ensure that vertilize is updating your containers once some resources has been loaded. Check this [runnable plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nrPhtfz5XVNLPF8Uvgk1?p=preview) and take a look at `angular-vertilize.min.js` inside this plnkr. In that way you are able to use this feature regardless of the number of async loaded resources.

```
<div vertilize-container class="row">
  <div ng-repeat="story in news" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div vertilize class="thumbnail">
      <img vertilize-resource ng-src="{{story.imgpath}}">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>{{story.title}}</h3>
        <p>{{story.subtitle}}</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I will go to push this feature to Github https://github.com/Sixthdim/angular-vertilize so its maybe available pretty soon. Here is the current pull request https://github.com/Sixthdim/angular-vertilize/pull/23 its maybe released in the next days.

Comment: Thanks, great contribution. @Gaurav provided an acceptable approach to set the image height, but it worked only as inline styling (not recommended) and it disallows responsive content.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need set the height of image inside the `ng-repeat`, because if you have slow network then image takes some time to download and the `angular-vertilize` plugin neglect the image height in calculation.

> You can use a `class` instead of `inline styling`

Working [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/m1yvronTDxb6fW7ZGwhX?p=preview)

```
<img ng-src="{{story.imgpath}}" alt="..." style="height: 150px;">
```

> Note: I've updated `src` to `ng-src` for dynamic binding